# Python Kivy. Why can't my function get the layout by it's id from the .kv file?

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to create a PageLayout. The second page must have some buttons and a scroll view, everything seems to be working. However, the error is:

```
     layout = self.ids.gridLay
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 841, in     kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__
 AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'
```

As I understand - this means that it can't find the id "gridLay" in the .kv file? I suppose that the function starts before the GridLayout was created.

Python:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.core.window import Window

screen_width = 450
screen_height = 800

Config.set("graphics", "resizable","1")
Config.set("graphics", "width", screen_width)

Config.set("graphics", "height", screen_height)

class MainScreen(Screen):
    def on_enter(self, *args):
        layout = self.ids.gridLay
        layout.bind(minimum_height=layout.setter('height'))

        scroll = ScrollView(size_hint=(1, 1))
        scroll.add_widget(layout)

class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass

presentation = Builder.load_file("final.kv")

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return presentation

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

Kivy:

```
ScreenManagement:
    MainScreen:

<MainScreen>:
    name: "main"

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "horizontal"

        BoxLayout:
            Widget:

        PageLayout:
            border: 15 
            orientation: "vertical"

            Widget:

            GridLayout:
                id: gridLay

                canvas:
                    Color:
                        rgba: (.156, .172, .24, 0.7)
                    Rectangle:
                        pos: self.pos
                        size: self.size


                cols: 1

                BoxLayout:
                    size_hint: (.45 , None)
                    size: (100, 300)

                    orientation: "vertical"

                    Widget:
                        size_hint: (1, .7)

                    Button:
                        background_color: (.2, .6, 0, 0.7)
                        text: "Button"  
                        size_hint: (1, .3)


                BoxLayout:
                    size_hint: (.45 , None)
                    size: (100, 300)

                    orientation: "vertical"

                    Widget:
                        size_hint: (1, .7)

                    Button:
                        background_color: (.2, .6, 0, 0.7)
                        text: "Button"  
                        size_hint: (1, .3)

                BoxLayout:
                    size_hint: (.45 , None)
                    size: (100, 300)

                    orientation: "vertical"

                    Widget:
                        size_hint: (1, .7)

                    Button:
                        background_color: (.2, .6, 0, 0.7)
                        text: "Button"  
                        size_hint: (1, .3)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are correct that the `on_enter` event is being dispatched too early. According to the [documentation](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html):

> on_enter: () 
>   Event fired when the screen is displayed: the entering animation is complete.

But the `Screen` display is not yet complete (as evidenced by the `ids` dictionary not being filled).

Here is a hack to get around what I think is a bug in `Kivy`. Separate the code that you want to execute into a new method, then call that method from the `on_enter` like this:

```
def on_enter(self, *args):
    if len(self.ids) == 0:
        Clock.schedule_once(self.do_on_enter_stuff)
    else:
        self.do_on_enter_stuff()

def do_on_enter_stuff(self, *args):
    layout = self.ids.gridLay
    layout.bind(minimum_height=layout.setter('height'))

    scroll = ScrollView(size_hint=(1, 1))
    scroll.add_widget(layout)
```

Really ugly, but I think it will work. By the way, your `scroll.add_widget(layout)` call will fail because the `layout` is already a child of your `PageLayout`.

Comment: Thank you, this is really helpfull. But how could I get around the problem with "scroll.add_widget(layout)". I have just tried to call "layout" the first BoxLayout instead of a GridLayout, so that I am using the layout that is not a child of anything accept <MainScreen> but it does not wirk still. It is going to be a child in any way...

Comment: The only ways to describe an element in a `.kv` file without having it be the child of another widget, is to either make it a root widget (like your `ScreenManagement`, but you cannot have two root widgets), or make it a rule (like your `MainScreen` rule), or a dynamic class (like `<Mygrid@GridLayout>`. If you make it a rule or dynamic class, then you can create an instance in your python code (instead of accessing it by ids), and it will not be a child of anything. If you also want another instance of that class to appear in your `PageLayout`, you would just reference `MyGrid`.